# Get the last seen time for Azure Hybrid worker group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I'm trying to retrieve the last seen time value for hybrid worker groups using PowerShell. However, I cannot find any of the parameters of "Get-AzureRMAutomationHybridWorkerGroup" or the members of this Cmdlet that can retrieve this value. I can see that I can only retrieve the registration time. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got it working by importing the latest Version 0.6.1 from the Az.Automation module.
the same is true for the "old" commandlet with prefix AzureRM and Version 6.13.1:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/6.13.1

The missing property thing was already fixed in September (https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/commit/e098199011c3ad09ef94a0b70f6de76f61bddd12#diff-f3a5751aabbc428aaa014a0c847c2e61)

[image]

```
PS /home/Falco> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.6.1      Az.Automation                       {Export-AzAutomationDscConfiguration, Export-AzAutomationDscNodeReportContent, Export-AzAutomationRunbook, Get-AzAutomationAccount...}
Script     0.6.1      Az.Profile                          {Add-AzEnvironment, Clear-AzContext, Clear-AzDefault, Connect-AzAccount...}
```

Version 0.5.0 was installed before and had the issue with missing date.

this will give you the desired result.

```
PS /home/Falco> (Get-AzAutomationHybridWorkerGroup -ResourceGroupName RG1 -AutomationAccountName Automationtest).RunbookWorker | fl


IpAddress        : 192.168.1.7,172.17.192.1,172.18.201.17
Name             : Server
RegistrationTime : 11/18/18 11:55:52 PM +00:00
LastSeenDateTime : 11/22/18 1:25:23 AM +00:00
```

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/ You should not install Az side-by-side with AzureRM. Remove all AzureRM modules before installing Az.

Answer (score 0):

this is an open issue with the `Get-AzureRmAutomationHybridWorkerGroup`commandlet, see
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5959

until fixed, you need to go the generic way and make some API calls:

first check
https://resources.azure.com and search for your resource and the missing properties.
then you are ready to retrieve them with powershell like this:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName RG1 -ResourceType Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/hybridRunbookWorkerGroups -ResourceName "AutomationTest" -ApiVersion 2015-10-31
```

even that generic Cmdlet only shows the following values, still do not retrieve the lastSeendatetime value:

Name
ResourceId
ResourceName
ResourceType
ResourceGroupName 
SubscriptionId

although the data is being sent as the debug ( `$DebugPreference="Continue"`) output shows:

```
Body:
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id":
"/subscriptions/12345xyz/resourceGroups/RG1/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/automationtest/hybridRunbookWorkerGr
oups/TestHy",
      "name": "TestHy",
      "hybridRunbookWorkers": [
        {
          "name": "Server1",
          "ip": "4.4.4.4",
          "registrationTime": "2018-11-19T00:55:52.0407467+01:00",
          "lastSeenDateTime": "2018-11-19T17:16:48.497+01:00",
          "azureResourceId": ""
        }
      ],
      "credential": null,
      "groupType": "User"
    }
  ]
}
```

as a dirt workaround, you can capture the debug output

`(Get-AzureRMAutomationHybridWorkerGroup -ResourceGroupName RG1 -AutomationAccountName test ) 5>&1 | Set-Variable out`
 and extract the lastSeenDateTime from that string e.g. with `$out | findstr "lastseen"`

check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/hybridrunbookworkergroup/get
to get the desired property by a REST call for the proper way, but authentication has then to be done again, but there are several hints you can google e.g. https://blog.tekspace.io/access-azure-rest-api-using-powershell/

Comment: I was able to see that result I wanted in https://resources.azure.com, but when I run the equal PowerShell Cmdlet which is the same as you displayed I cannot get the Last Seen Time in the result.

Comment: you will have to adjust the resourcename / resourcetype accordingly and try the expandproperties option of the powershell command. I cannot test that because I don't have hybrid workers running. I know it's a bit of fiddling…

Comment: That's what I've done and still cannot see last seen time in the properties.

Comment: I have no idea how to further help, when you don't provide any of the results you get and show what is missing.

Comment: Please, check the question for the result.

Comment: you are right! it ignores the array containing the value. you can test it by issueing ` $DebugPreference="Continue"`  before. I'll investigate further

Comment: I already tried to the invoke-webrequest Cmdlet to get it by a REST call, but it results in "{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}"

Comment: @Krank I revised my answer with nearly all known workarounds and issues… :)

Comment: @Krank did you check my 2nd answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Powershell and Azure Rest API:

```
Connect-AzAccount;

$automationAccountName = 'xxxxx';
$resourceGroupName = 'rg_xxxxxxxxx';
$subscriptionId = '11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555';


$uri="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/$automationAccountName/hybridRunbookWorkerGroups?api-version=2022-02-22";

$token = Get-AzAccessToken;

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer " + "$($token.token)"
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers;

$workerGroups = $result.value.name;

foreach ($wg in $workerGroups) {
    Get-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker -AutomationAccountName $automationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName $wg | Select-Object WorkerName, LastSeenDateTime;
}
```

Output:

WorkerName   LastSeenDateTime

---

azvmhybrid1  2/15/2023 3:21:36 PM +00:00